# How would I structure this database?

Tags: php, mysql

Apologies for another question on a similar topic, but I'm inexperienced at this level of database development.

I have a project in which users join projects, a page where content is loaded dynamically from a MySQL database. I've been exploring foreign keys and the like to deal with the many-to-many aspects of having several users to a project and vice versa, but where should all of the content that is loaded into each project be stored? Amongst other things, I have a chat window and a place to upload and download files.

Comment: what do you mean with"where should all of the content that is loaded into each project be stored"? that looks like THE question??

Comment: Each project page will be dynamic, with users being able to add and remove various elements of the page e.g. the file upload I mentioned. Like a Facebook page would have lots of wall posts, where is that all stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for

```
Project
id
proejectName
startDate
endDate
title
description
[... basically all project specific content]

ProjectParticipant
userId
projectId

User
id
username
email
[... basically all user specific content]
```

`ProjectParticipant` is a many-to-many table, linking the user to the project and vice versa.

**EDIT:**

If you want to represent project specifc files or project specific comments then you need to create seperate tables for these things because one project has many comments and one project most likely also got many files. So you could create two tables like the following:

```
ProjectComment
id
projectId (references the id of the project table)
authorId (references the id of the user table)
comment
created_at

ProjectFile
id
projectId (references the id of the project table)
fileLocation 
uploadedBy (references the id of the user table)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's more or less what I have now, but what do I do with all of the dynamic content e.g. the forum-style posts etc? It looks like I was unclear, see my above clarification in the comments.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have comments and maybe files that is specific for the project?

Comment: Yep, that's right - each project has its own comments and files.

Comment: So you create another table called ProjectComment (for example) and in it is a table ID and a list of comments for each?

Comment: Yea, Basically, if you send a comment to a project with id 1, assuming you got userId 1, the following would be inserted as a row in the table: id=1, projectId=1, authorId=1, comment="Nice project dude!", created_at = "2011-11-02 21:42:00". Then I with userId 2 send a comment to the same project, then a new row would get inserted like this: id=2, projectId=1, authorId=2, comment="I agree ..!", created_at = "2011-11-02 21:44:00".

Comment: And if you want to upload a file to the same project, you would insert a row in the ProjectFile table like this: id=1, projectId=1, fileLocation="nice_pic.png" ,uploadedBy=1. :D

Comment: Thanks very much, that's really cleared up a lot for me!